# Mapping a list as dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings called lst which contains name, city, and email addresses for three people in such order. I have a dictionary called data that only contains keys.

```
lst = ['James','New York','james@email.com','Matt','San Francisco','matt@email.com','Jessica','Los Angeles','jessica@email.com']

data = {
            "Name": None,
            "City": None,
            "email": None
        }
```

I would like to map lst items as values in data and produce a new list of dictionaries as below,

```
newlst = [{
            "Name": "James",
            "City": "New York",
            "email": "james@email.com"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Matt",
            "City": "San Francisco",
            "email": "matt@email.com"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Jessica",
            "City": "Los Angeles",
            "email": "jessica@email.com"
        }]
```

I know how to add a single value to a specific key in a dictionary like data["Name"] = "James" but how would I achieve this by using list/dict comprehension or iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is.

```
lst = ['James','New York','james@email.com','Matt','San Francisco','matt@email.com','Jessica','Los Angeles','jessica@email.com']
newlst = []

for i in xrange( 0, len(lst), 3 ):
    d = {}
    d['Name'] = lst[i]
    d['City'] = lst[i+1]
    d['Email'] = lst[i+2]

    newlst.append( d )

print newlst
```

Output:

```
[{'City': 'New York', 'Email': 'james@email.com', 'Name': 'James'},
 {'City': 'San Francisco', 'Email': 'matt@email.com', 'Name': 'Matt'},
 {'City': 'Los Angeles', 'Email': 'jessica@email.com', 'Name': 'Jessica'}]
```

Using comprehension:

```
lst = ['James','New York','james@email.com','Matt','San Francisco','matt@email.com','Jessica','Los Angeles','jessica@email.com']
newlst = [{'Name':lst[i], 'City':lst[i+1], 'Email':lst[i+2]} for i in xrange(0,len(lst),3)]
```

Comment: To make this more python 3 friendly, might want to make a note that `range` *has* to be used for Python 3 and `print newlst` => `print(newlst)`

Comment: You could also save a couple of lines, and do `newlst.append({'Name': lst[i], 'City': lst[i], 'Email': lst[i]})`

Comment: Could save a lot of lines using comprehension :) I've added to the answer.

Comment: Yeah. I liked your approach @DavidZemens

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach using list comprehension. The idea is that we create a dictionary based on a zip of the keys and three values of a time.

```
lst = [
    'James', 'New York', 'james@email.com',
    'Matt', 'San Francisco', 'matt@email.com',
    'Jessica', 'Los Angeles', 'jessica@email.com',
]

keys = [
    'Name',
    'City',
    'email',
]

newlst = [
    dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in [iter(lst)] * len(keys)
]
print(newlst)
```

**Output**:

```
[
    {'City': 'New York', 'Name': 'James', 'email': 'james@email.com'},
    {'City': 'San Francisco', 'Name': 'Matt', 'email': 'matt@email.com'},
    {'City': 'Los Angeles', 'Name': 'Jessica', 'email': 'jessica@email.com'}
]
```

`[iter(lst)] * len(keys)` will return chunks of 3 values at a time from the list. `zip(keys, values)` will then produce an iterator of tuples containing a key and corresponding value. Finally, `dict()` will turn this into a dictionary to be inserted into `newlst`. This loops until the list is exhausted.